# Creating a text file on local machine using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, text, export-to-csv

I would like to know how to create a text file and save it on my local machine, below is the stored procedure I am using. It creates the text file on server but I want it to be created on my local machine.

Any help is much appreciated..

```
alter Procedure [dbo].[USP_SaveFile]
    (@text as NVarchar(Max), @Filename Varchar(200)) AS
Begin
    declare
        @Object int,
        @rc int,
        @FileID Int

    EXEC @rc = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @Object OUT
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @Object , 'OpenTextFile' , @FileID OUT , @Filename , 2 , 1
    Set @text = Replace(Replace(Replace(@text,'&','&'),'<' ,'<'),'>','>')
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @FileID , 'WriteLine' , Null , @text
    Exec @rc = [databasename].dbo.sp_OADestroy @FileID

    Declare @Append bit

    Select @Append = 0

    If @rc <> 0
    Begin
        Exec @rc = [databasename].dbo.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SaveFile',null,@text ,@Filename,@Append
    End

    Exec @rc = [databasename].dbo.sp_OADestroy @Object
End

--  Use [databasename]
--  EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
--  GO
--  EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
--  GO
--  RECONFIGURE;
--  GO
--  EXEC USP_SaveFile 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008', 'D:\sqlfiles\test.txt'
```

Comment: I take it that SSIS is not available to you?  That's really a better tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

Create a share on your local machine and then use it like this:

```
EXEC USP_SaveFile 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008', '\\YourMachine\dir1\dir2\test.txt'
```

Please mind that SQL Server is a service so this: [Network Service account accessing a folder share](https://serverfault.com/questions/41130/network-service-account-accessing-a-folder-share) apply to it.

Comment: +1 for the answer, @Michał Powaga is there any other method to achieve the same as i am not having the permissions of sharing the folder.

Comment: No, sorry. The only thing I think about is client side application that executes procedure and saves returned result set (or output parameter). But it won't happen on server side as you want to.